# SharePoint - Content Query Web Part MaxListsLimit

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I´m now using the Content Query Web Part for more than 2 years.
Everthing works fine.
But now, I think I reached the MaxListsLimit value.
The Webpart is not returning any value.

> ULS Error: Error occured while processing a Content Query Web Part
>
> The query cannot be completed because the number of lists in the query
>   exceeded the allowable limit

The default for is MaxListsLimit 1000 and I wan´t to set it to 0
But how can I define MaxListsLimit for the Webpart?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SharePoint online or on-premise?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 on-premise